# access page only if logged in with php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm new to PHP, and I want to make possible to access a page only if a person is logged in.
login2.php:

```
<?php

$host="hostxyz";
$dbusername="userxyz";
$dbpassword="xyz";
$db_name="dbxyz";
$tbl_name="tblxyz";

mysql_connect("$host", "$dbusername", "$dbpassword")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['pwd'];
$encryptedpwd=sha1($password);

$username = stripslashes($username);
$encryptedpwd = stripslashes($encryptedpwd);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$encryptedpwd = mysql_real_escape_string($encryptedpwd);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and pwd='$encryptedpwd'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1){

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['pwd'] = $encryptedpwd; 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Username e/o password errata.";
}
?>
```

login_success.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username']){
header("location:area_utenti.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

area_utenti.php (member_area.php translated):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("location:dologin.html");
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Area Utenti</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Sei loggato, bravoh!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

dologin.html is simply a page where unregistered/unlogged users are redirected if they try to access to member area.
The problem is that after I log in, I should be redirected to area_utenti.php, but area_utenti.php redirects me to dologin.html. What did I do wrong? 
Sorry for bad English.

P.S.: I tried to search for solutions on StackOverflow, and I tried to apply them, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to start the session in one of your scripts, maybe thats the issue, might worth checking it:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="hostxyz";
$dbusername="userxyz";
$dbpassword="xyz";
$db_name="dbxyz";
$tbl_name="tblxyz";
//...rest of your code...
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, can't believe I didn't see it before, after all the time I spent searching for the error :)