# need to show page only if a user logged in php

Tags: php, sql, session

Sorry for a duplicate question, but its not working for me;

[access page only if logged in with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725366/access-page-only-if-logged-in-with-php)

i have to access display.php page if someone loggedin, if they enter the url directly it need to redirect to login.php page,
i tried sessions but its not working for me, please help me to debug it.

**display.php**

```
    <?php
    session_start();
            if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
            {
                  header("location: login.php");
            }
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","zaq12345","testdb");
    if(!$conn)
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $disp = "select * from formdata order by user_id desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$disp);
    ?>
           <button onclick="location.href='formnew1.html';">Add</button>
           <table border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tr>
                         <th> ID </th>
                         <th> Name </th>
                         <th> Email </th>
                         <th> Age </th>
                         <th> Gender </th>
                         <th> Address </th>
                         <th> City </th>
                         <th> Skills </th>
                         <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                         //$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                          {
                                $id = $row['user_id']; ?>
                                <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['user_id']?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['email']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['age']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['gender']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['address']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['city']?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['skill']?></td>
                                <td>
                                <a id="edit" href="edit1.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
                                <a href="#" id= "<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                     <?php  }  ?>  
           </table>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script>
           function deleteRow(obj){
                  conf=confirm('Are you sure to delete the Data');
                  if(conf){
                         var tr = $(obj).closest('tr');
                         $.post("delete1.php", {id: obj.id}, function(result){
                               tr.fadeOut('slow', function(){
                               $(obj).remove();
                               });
                         });
                  }
           }
    </script>
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['success']))
    {

            echo '<script> alert("Data Added Successfully");</script>';
            }
    else if (isset($_SESSION['fail'])){
           echo '<script> alert("Failed to Store");</script>';
           //header("Location: /training/formnew.html");
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

***login.php***

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
     <style>
        div {
                color: rgb(255,0,0);
            }
       form {
               max-width: 425px;
               margin: 10px auto;
               padding: 10px 20px;
               background: #ff994580;
               border-radius: 10px;
            }
     fieldset {
               margin-top: 100px ;
               margin-bottom: 500px;
               border: none;
               }
     h2        {
            margin: 0 0 30px 0;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Calibri';
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: 300;
                }
     label        {

            font-family: 'Calibri';
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 50;
                }
    .submit {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.reset {
    background-color: #ff3333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
    </style>
     </head>
<body>
     <fieldset>
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="validate.php">
  <H2> LOGIN </H2>
  <table width="60%" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>User ID</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="user_id" name="user_id"placeholder="Enter your User ID" required="required"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>User Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter your Username" required="required"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Password</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required="required"/>
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Login">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="reset" class="reset"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</fieldset>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**validate.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","zaq12345","testdb");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
     $userid=$_POST['user_id'];
     $username=$_POST['user_name'];
     $password=$_POST['password'];
     $qz = "SELECT * FROM userdata WHERE user_id = '$userid' AND user_name = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
     $result=mysqli_query($conn,$qz);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1 )
     {
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
            header('location: display1.php');  
     }
     else{
          $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
          echo '<script> alert("ERROR: Please Check Credentials OR SignUp!!!"); window.location.href="login.php"; </script>';
     }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: i can do login validation with these files. but if i enter the url directly it shows the content

Comment: in validate.php don't use `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false` just remove it, because you set it even if its false but it is set

Comment: Alternatively, you can do `if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == false)` (since you set it to false in your validate.php if the validation failed). Or, you can do set it to `null` instead of `false`.

Comment: *Curious:* Are you going live with this? Edit: I sure hope not.

Comment: **Don't store your passwords in plain-text!** This is not secure *at all!* PHP has built-in functions which you should use to handle storing of passwords, see the [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function 
which is a lot more secure!

Comment: You should also take advantage of parameterized queries, which `mysqli_*` offers. Take a look at `mysqli::prepare()`

Comment: Where are you destroying that SESSION['loggedin'] information? Because once it'll get set in SESSION array it'll be available throughout the application as long as we'll not destroy it explicitly or restart the the system.

Comment: You will also need and `exit;` after the `header()` as a `header()` does not terminate the scripts execution

Comment: @Fred-ii- it looks live

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Akin Well, it probably won't be for long :-(

Comment: prepared statements have been introduced for a while now and yet @Fred-ii-

Comment: Surely it cannot be LIVE, OP is using `root` as the user account. **Surely nobody would do that in a LIVE system** :)

Comment: @Akin and `password_hash()` / `password_verify()` just to name a few more ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly You'd be surprised

Comment: @RiggsFolly well, maybe they chose their localhost setting to be set as live, who knows.

Comment: yes its not live, im using in local server

Comment: and where to unset sessions

Comment: back to the question. Leaving other errors like storing passwords in plain text and others, on the page, why dont you just check if session loggedin is true or false.

Comment: In validate.php you are redirecting the user to display1.php using the function : header('location: display1.php');  . Should it be display.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the line `$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;` in your `validate.php` file.

Or change the if statement in your `display.php` file to be

`if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'] || !$_SESSION['loggedin'])`

You are setting the `loggedin` to be false, so when you call `isset` it returns true, because it is set even though it is set to false.